# Is it possible for Visual Studio look for Include and Library files recursively?

Tags: visual-studio

I am working on a custom game engine, and I use several libraries. Is some way to make Visual Studio 2022 look recursively in sub-folders? For example, I want to keep all of my compiled libraries in a

```
SolutionDir/libs
```

and then be able to allow it to find:

```
SolutionDir/libs/box2d/x86/Debug
SolutionDir/libs/box2d/x86/Debug
```

Based on the solution config.

My attempt was to set, for example, the all-inclusive 'include' directory to be $(SolutionDir)/
With subfolders per lib include so that I could have:

```
$(SolutionDir)include/SDL2_image-2.0.5/include
$(SolutionDir)include/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/include
$(SolutionDir)include/SDL2_ttf-2.0.18/include
$(SolutionDir)include/SDL2-2.0.20/include
$(SolutionDir)include/box2d-main/include
$(SolutionDir)include/box2d-main/include/simple_json
```

All recursively found under

```
$(SolutionDir)include
```

But it doesn't seem to look past the given directory. Note that I'd like to do this for both library directories in project configuration, and include paths.